# bash find: Variable list of find path exclusions to array

Tags: bash, find

I have a script that has `find` looping through an external file with a list of paths in order to build file lists for `rsync`.  These paths have a variable amount of path exclusions (including none at all). I'm trying to expand a variable which builds out the `find` exclusions based on this. I have researched plenty and am stumped. Say:

`cat backuplist.conf`:

```
/mnt/some/dir1 /mnt/some/dir1/exclude/dirA /mnt/some/dir1/exclude/dirB
/mnt/some/dir2
```

and the relevant part of the main backup script is:

`cat backupscript.sh`:

```
while read backuppath excludedir1 excludedir2 excludedir3; do
    exclude=("${excludedir1}" "${excludedir2}" "${excludedir3}")  
    find ${backuppath} -not \( -path "*${exclude[0]}" "${exclude[@]:1}") -mtime -10 > file.list
    rsync -vPaz --files-from=file.list --otheroptions
  done < backuplist.conf
```

I know I've got that array example all wrong (among else), but I don't even know if building an array is the right solution, given that it doesn't know how many exclusions there will be. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Bash/CentOS 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the excluded directories in an array and then use `printf` to print them out in the `find` command.

```
while read backuppath excludeDirs; do
    excludeArr=( $excludeDirs )
    if [[ ${#excludeArr[@]} == 0 ]]
    then
        find "${backuppath}" -mtime -10 > file.list
    elif [[ ${#excludeArr[@]} == 1 ]]
    then
        find "${backuppath}" -mtime -10 -not -path "${excludeArr[0]}"  > file.list
    else
        find "${backuppath}" -mtime -10  -not \( -path "${excludeArr[0]}" $(printf -- '-o -path "%s" ' "${excludeArr[@]:1}") \) > file.list
    fi
    rsync -vPaz --files-from=file.list --otheroptions
done < backuplist.conf
```

Comment: I would warn about directory names that contain spaces, but given the input file format, we may have to assume that all paths are space-free.

Comment: Thanks for all the help-- it's exactly what I couldn't find. However, I can't get multiple exclusions to work. The loop is getting it to the third `find`, and whatever the first exclusion is is getting skipped in the find, but any second or third exclusion in the array gets ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: On second thought, I think I can manage it. Got ! \( -name -o -name )\ to work on the command line (which I couldn't even get to work with -not -path. Just have to work it in and get the syntax correct. Thanks again, dogbane.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, I'm sure dogbane's solution is perfectly correct; It's my own inexperience that's giving me issue.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments... pretty exciting stuff. It's working perfectly with dogbone's original solution. I did have to remove the quotes from printf's "%s" to get it to work, but it could have been something locally specific requiring this. I'll upvote when I have enough credentials. Thanks again.